# Windows forms stratification

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am writing my Windows Forms app. And I have some problem with TableLayoutContainer element. Or rows are superpose (without needed scroll bar) or there is a big interval between first and second row.
I need a container with dynamic changing sizes according to Form size, with auto vertical scroll (if the container's size to big). Please help me to correct my code or container's properties.

```
            Label LabelG = new Label[len];
            NumericUpDown NumberControlBars = new NumericUpDown[len];

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
            TablePanelContainer.RowCount++;
            TablePanelContainer.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 25F));                

            LabelG[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            LabelG[i].Name = "Label" + i.ToString();
            LabelG[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 23);
            LabelG[i].Text = Groups[i].ToString();
            LabelG[i].Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            LabelG[i].Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);
            LabelG[i].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;                
            TablePanelContainer.Controls.Add(LabelG[i], 0, i);

            NumberControlBars[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            NumberControlBars[i].Name = "Label" + i.ToString();
            NumberControlBars[i].MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(40,23);
            NumberControlBars[i].Text = "0";
            NumberControlBars[i].Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            NumberControlBars[i].Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);
            TablePanelContainer.Controls.Add(NumberControlBars[i], 1, i);
            }
```

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW3QQ.jpg)
[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yg3Q.jpg)

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I have incorrect working of TableLayoutContainer (example of bug is on the picture attached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your functionality in a small app. These are the settings for your TablePanelLayout control

- Anchor: Top, Bottom, Left, Right
- AutoScroll: True
- AutoSize: False

Specially the `AutoSize` setting to false is important. If you don't do that the control will resize itself to the height needed to accommodate all rows. Because the container has enough space in that case to show everything it will not show the scrollbars. It doesn't care that its size doesn't fit on the form.

This is what the designer should look like:

[image: tablelayoutpanel in design mode and properties]

To overcome the quirks with the first row I adapted the Style of that first row. It looks like the designer plays some tricks here. Your code will look like this.

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
// adapt styling of first row
if (tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count > 0)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0].Height = 25F;
}
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    var lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = i.ToString();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, i);

    var num = new NumericUpDown();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(num,1 ,i);

    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
}

tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

When run this is the result:

[image: animation of code execution]

Comment: You put 1000 times more effort into your answer than the poster did into their question.

Comment: Yeah, but where's the free popcorn?

Comment: Once we were all young and didn't have experience enough. Thank you @rene